# Is it at all possibleto use %(%d)d or something similiar to this instead of %3d in C programming

Tags: c

I was specifically trying to print integer type using `%3d` but out of curiosity I want to know if it is at all possible to print `%(%d)d`, considering `3` could be an integer. 
Tried searching a lot online but only could find basics of `%d,`%f` etc.

Comment: Yes, you write %*d, see the linked answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can print on a variable width with this syntax:

```
printf("%*d", width, number);
```

Comment: thanks it works for me